# Auto login using "remember me" not working

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I am new to Yii2. I'm using Yii 2 basic template.

I have the "remember me" functionality implemented on my web application, but it is not working as I think it was supposed to. I can successfully log in (with a checked "remember me" checkbox). But after closing the browser and opening the website again I am not logged in, but instead redirected to the login page.

I have set `enableAutoLogin` to `true` in the config file

```
'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
         'authTimeout' => 86400,
    ],
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Yii 2, but does this functionality work using cookies? If so, are you perhaps using a browser option to delete cookies after closing the browser?

Comment: Have you made sure your `cookieValidationKey` is set in config/web.php

Answer (score 4):

**1.** Do this in your user (if using any other model for login then use that model) model.

add this just before `rules`

`public $rememberMe = true;`

and define in your model

```
public function login()
{
     if ($this->validate()) {
         return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
     }
     return false;
}
```

**2.** now do this in your view page

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'rememberMe')->checkbox(['template' => "<div class=\"col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-3\">{input} {label}</div>\n<div class=\"col-lg-8\">{error}</div>"]) ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your user model have implemented `yii\web\IdentityInterface` and it has the following methods

1. findIdentity()
2. findIdentityByAccessToken()
3. getId()
4. getAuthKey()
5. validateAuthKey()

   use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

    /**
     * Finds an identity by the given ID.
     *
     * @param string|integer $id the ID to be looked for
     * @return IdentityInterface|null the identity object that matches the given ID.
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return static::findOne($id);
    }

    /**
     * Finds an identity by the given token.
     *
     * @param string $token the token to be looked for
     * @return IdentityInterface|null the identity object that matches the given token.
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        return static::findOne(['access_token' => $token]);
    }

    /**
     * @return int|string current user ID
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string current user auth key
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->auth_key;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $authKey
     * @return boolean if auth key is valid for current user
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
    }
}
```

Refer [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authentication.html) for more about auto login

Answer (score 2):

Using **"Remember Me"** in the **login** :

**1-** Create your identity class using this link : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authentication.html

**2-** Add this line to the config file :

...

```
'components' => [
    'user' => [
        'enableAutoLogin' => true, /* Whether to enable cookie-based login. */
    ],
],
```

...

**3-** Use this code after you validate login form :

```
/* If [[enableSession]] is `true`:
- the identity information will be stored in session and be available in the next requests
- in case of `$duration == 0`: as long as the session remains active or till the user closes the browser
- in case of `$duration > 0`: as long as the session remains active or as long as the cookie
  remains valid by it's `$duration` in seconds when [[enableAutoLogin]] is set `true`.
  */
$duration = $this->remember ? (30 * 24 * 3600) : 0;
Yii::$app->user->login($user, $duration);
```