# Yii2 set session timeout for 3 days

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have session configuration as follows

```
'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\LoginForm',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            'loginUrl' => ['/login'],
            'identityCookie' => [
                'name' => '_OwnerUser', // unique for frontend
            ],
            'authTimeout' => 1800,
        ],
        'session' => [
            'name' => 'PHPOWNERSESSID',
            'savePath' => sys_get_temp_dir(),
            'timeout'=> 1800
        ],
```

What I want to do is keep user logged in for 3 days, I have gone through the SO. In which way I can implement this?

1. Is it necessary to use cookies for storing session? if yes then how?
2. I want to implement it in my existing project which is in production and I have not used cookie for login purpose

Comment: This answer can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43993420/2042775

Comment: @sj59 answer provided by you is based on cookie, can I implement it without using cookie? or using any php.ini setting

Comment: this link can halp you to change the default value of session timout: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9904195/2042775

Comment: I have tries with `session.gc_maxlifetime` but its not working

Comment: @NitinP no u shoudn't use php session to store for so long time. Use cookie.

Comment: @SiZE and sj59 : Thank you for your comments.. I will go for cookie