# yii2 remember me default checked, how can I uncheck?

Tags: checkbox, yii2, remember-me

When I login in yii2, unchecked remember me but I always get remember me as checked in login form.

How can we unchecked by default.
Here is the controller code

```
public function login() {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

`$this->rememberMe` always gets yes.

Comment: Show your view file code.

Comment: <input name="rememberMe" tabindex="5" type="checkbox" id="General">

Comment: in your LoginForm set remeberMe default value to false, 
`public $rememberMe = false;`

Comment: may be you could refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450580/auto-login-using-remember-me-not-working)

Comment: If i set remeberMe default value to false then how can i get the value of rememberMe, may be pass from controller to LoginForm, am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set bydefult checked is false

```
public $rememberMe = false;
```